# Win8 'run prompt' is not showing a UAC prompt if logged in as a lower user. (But did in Win7.) How do I get the old behavior back?

Tags: windows-8, uac

While running as a lower user in Windows 7, if I run, say, "services.msc" in the run prompt UAC pops up and allows me to either run it as the [current] lower user OR to enter administrative credentials to run it with elevation.

Windows 8 does not show this prompt and automatically runs everything as a lower user. (In other words, I don't get the UAC prompt and thus have no chance to enter administrative credentials.)

How do I change the Win8 behavior to replicate the Win7 behavior?

The same problem is observed when attempting to launch anything from the "Administrative Tools" section from the control panel. No UAC prompt ever occurs and I would like it to. (The prompt would occur in Win7 but does not happen in Win8.)

Note: UAC settings are set to "Always Notify" on both systems.

Edit: Things like secpol.msc & gpedit.msc jump straight to "Access Denied" and do not prompt for admin credentials (And I want them to)